# Is there a way on newer Android systems to trigger a receiver when no network is available?

Tags: android, performance, android-networking

On older Android systems(`< Build.VERSION_CODES.N`) it was possible to find the device didn't have any network connected using  `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />` in the manifest, when your app/service was not running.

On newer Android systems you can still wake a receiver when a network has specific capability or transport using [registerNetworkCallback (NetworkRequest request,PendingIntent operation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) or [requestNetwork(NetworkRequest request, PendingIntent operation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#requestNetwork(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), example:

```
//...
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    fun registerPIntent(context: Context){
        val nR = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                .build()

        val intent = Intent(context, DataConnReceiver::class.java)
        val networkPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
        cm?.requestNetwork(nR, networkPendingIntent)
    }
//...
```

The problem is that you don't have a way on newer android systems to wakeup a receiver when there is no network connected it would be great if there was something like `NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_NONE` but there's not.

I know you can use either a foreground service or `WorkManager` to make periodic checks to see if the phone is connected to a network( but that would not be very performant).

I suspect there isn't an efficient way on newer android systems to wakeup a reciver when the phone is not connected to a network, but in case anybody knows a way, I would very much like to know that way, I just want to be sure.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that broadcasts were deprecated in favor or more robust callbacks. Is there a reason why you need to rely on a broadcast vs a callback?

Comment: Callbacks using `registerNetworkCallback()` or `requestNetwork()` do not outlive your app, unless you pass a `PendingIntent` (a receiver) the problem is that when you pass a `PendingIntent` you can only wake your app when a specific network is connected, but not when that network will be disconnected.     At the moment after a network is connected I use `WorkManager` to scan until it disconnects and after the disconnect, I use `requestNetwork()` with a pending intent so I can do that all over again, it works but I want a more efficient way.